# Comparing and concatenating with perl?

Tags: perl

Concatenating a string with the ternary operator:

This works:

```
 $additional .= "   <tr>
                          <td>$wrow{perc_chng}</td>
                   </tr>";
```

This doesn't

```
$additional .= "    <tr>
                        <td " . $wrow{perc_chng} > 0 ? "bgcolor='#009900'" :
     $wrow{perc_chng} < 0 ? "bgcolor='#009900'" : '' . ">$wrow{perc_chng}</td>
                              </tr>";
```

and gives:

```
`Argument ">-29.7625</td>\n^I^I^I^I^I^I  <td 44.5936" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at ...`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `use diagnostics;` to make more verbose warning.

Answer (score 3):

What is happening here is that the [precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) of the ternary operator `?:` is lower than the precedence of the numeric comparison operators, as you can see in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

You can use parentheses to enforce the correct order of execution:

```
$additional .= "   <tr>
                    <td " . ( $wrow{perc_chng} > 0 ? 
"bgcolor='#009900'" : $wrow{perc_chng} < 0 ? 
"bgcolor='#009900'" : '') . ">$wrow{perc_chng}</td>
                      </tr>";
```

As I understand it, you do not want to change colour if there is no change (perc_chng == 0), and then your logic would be better written as:

```
$additional .= "   <tr>
                    <td " . ( $wrow{perc_chng} == 0 ? 
"" : "bgcolor='#009900'" ) . ">$wrow{perc_chng}</td>
                      </tr>";
```

I believe if I wanted to affect a colour change, I would use a subroutine for it, such as:

```
sub td_colour {
    my $num = shift;
    if ($num >= 0) {
        return qq(<td bgcolor='#009900'>$num</td>);
    } else {
        return qq(<td>$num</td>);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to colour if it is unchanged (stayed same), are you sure brackets around the inner ternary aren't required?

Comment: Your logical is a bit complicated there. I would probably prefer to check if the number was equal to zero, or not: `$num == 0 ? "bgcolor..." : ""`

Answer (score 0):

For comparison of strings you should use operators: `lt` instead of `<` and `gt` instead of `>`.

Examples:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

if ('aba' > 1) {print "This will not be printed\n"; }
if ('aba' gt 1) {print "but this will be printed\n"; }
```

Output:

```
Argument "aba" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at test.pl line 6.
but this will be printed
```

Comment: This is clearly the wrong answer, as the OP is not trying to compare strings, but trying to colour negative numbers in HTML code.

Comment: I am getting `$wrow{perc_change}` from db, it is `5.24` for example, would this still apply?

Comment: @StevieG Your number is not a number. Use `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $wrow{perc_change};` to see what you actually have in the variable.

Comment: @StevieG Actually, scrap that. You are probably suffering from precedence issues, where concatenation `.` occurs before `>` numeric comparison. Your code does not seem to make sense as it is. Either you did something else before it that was wrong, or this is not the actual code.

Comment: @StevieG I have added an answer with the solution. :D